# Content problem, any better solution?

Tags: php, asp.net, web-applications, architecture, system

Currently i'm building an system that will let the user to create an small website inside their system. To access their website, user will type www.USERDOMAIN.mywebsite.com (just an example...)

Well, USERDOMAIN will be their username on my database, and mywebsite will be the system domain.

The user, (if he want's) can show his website on any domain, and i was thinking on how to link their domain with the information inside my database.

I thought on two ideas:

- I can't give the main code to the final user, so I just thought I'd give him an HTML page with an iframe targeted to the original content, but it would be an bad idea because i would have too much trafic from many websites, and everything will be on my database causing it to be slow down.
- Create some basic tables on the domain that my client has acquired, and some files to get the data and work with them, any change on the content would be made by the main system, them all chandged data would be sent to my client database

I Think that the second solution would be better, but if you had an experience like it, something that you had think, it would be really great to share with me...

if you had any idea, just let me know what of the two options above you chose.
Thanks guys!

Comment: It does not look like you have specific bandwidth problems, please change at least the title of your question. Thanks.

Comment: Yeh, you're right. I will change it, just after post i saw that any way that i chose it will have the sane traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be completely wrong here but if I understand right you want to do something like

www.userdomain.com shows the content of www.userdomain.mywebsite.com

Why not simply use CNAME records and create aliases that link the two? The user would need ot create the alias on their DNS settings but that would do it I'd think.

Comment: Ok, you're correct, i just wanna to show the same content.
I never tryed to use CNAME, it would redirect the user to the domain? Or just show the content?

Comment: It would just show the content. it would mask the domain so people wouldn't realize they were pulling it from www.userdomain.mywebsite.com they'd just see www.userdomain.com in the address bar.

Comment: This is an Nice idea, i will just see if anyone post other solution. Thanks!